# Do any MVVM libraries implement CommandSinkBinding?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am referring to the CommandSinkBinding as described in Josh Smiths article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VMCommanding.aspx

Comment: do you realize that this article is from 2008? In the comments they say that it is deprecated and Josh Smith himself replied that [RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) is the way to go.

Comment: What does RelayCommand have to do with implementing command sinks for RoutedUICommands? I am using CommandBindings to respond to Routed Commands... the only problem is the CommandBindings only let you take action using event handlers. Instead I want to bind the routed command to a command in my VM.

Comment: [just want to point you at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710630/delegate-command-and-routed-command/5717091#5717091)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a nice wrapper for UI to ViewModel command routing, you might look at [Cinch](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CinchV2_3.aspx#SimpleCommand).